# Display field value- not label?

Tags: visualforce, html

I can't get my VF working quite right. Here is the structure of the row of my table. the values were hard coded in the past, but now i want to change it to values of fields. The problem that I'm having is that when I do  `<apex:outputText value={!opp.field__c}/>` I'm getting the field label. Is there a way to avoid this? I'd prefer not to change my controller.

```
 <tr style="border:1px solid black">
        <td style="border:1px solid black">External Origin<br />(attributes of the environment)</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid black" valign="top">
            <b>Opportunities</b>
            <div id="ctl03_divOpportunityHTML">
                <ul>
                    <li style='list-style:disc; margin-left:2px'><a href='#4' style='text-decoration:none'>blah</a></li>
                    <li style='list-style:disc; margin-left:2px'><a href='#5' style='text-decoration:none'>blah</a></li>
                    <li style='list-style:disc; margin-left:2px'><a href='#6' style='text-decoration:none'>blah</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="border:1px solid black" valign="top">
            <b>Threats</b>
            <div id="ctl03_divThreatsHTML">
                <ul>
                    <li style='list-style:disc; margin-left:2px'><a href='#7' style='text-decoration:none'>blah</a></li>
                    <li style='list-style:disc; margin-left:2px'><a href='#8' style='text-decoration:none'>blah</a></li>
                    <li style='list-style:disc; margin-left:2px'><a href='#9' style='text-decoration:none'>blah</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question :/ what do you want to "replace with fields"? There's not a single `{!merge field}` in sight. You want pieces of CSS to come from some string variables? or say a textarea to appear in the table as unescaped (= dangerous) HTML? Or are you looking for stuff like `{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.LabelPlural}` so if "Opportunities" is translated it'll be just picked up?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I want to replace the <ul /> with the value from a custom text area- but i don't want to include it's label

Comment: `<apex:outputText value="{!yourField__c}" escape="false" />` ? Or outputPanel?

Comment: You seriously get field label with outputText? weird, should be only with outputField I'd say...

Comment: @eyescream, I've had funny-experiences with getting the label to display correctly.  I think it only displays the label in a `apex:pageBlockSection` (maybe a `apex:pageBlock` too)

Comment: Would overriding the label with an empty string work? Eg, apex:outputField value="{!field__c}" label="" -- this would leave the html table the same as for with the label, but the label wouldn't show.

Comment: @amatorVitae thanks you were right about the  apex:pageblocksection causing the wierdness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to display the values - no labels - just do this:

```
<li>{!MyObject__c.Field__c}</li>
```

this will display your value - but not editable. if you want to be able to edit the values - you would want to use input text - not inputField

```
<li><apex:inputText value={!MyObject__c.Field__c}" /></li>
```

you will not get the label this way